# How can I hide important headers from http request

Tags: javascript, security, http-headers

We have created an javascript SDK which our clients can integrate in their websites. They will have to initialise the SDK using this method

```
    `initializeMethod.init({
      PROJECT_ID: 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX',
      API_KEY: 'XXXX-XXX-XXXX',
      email: '',
      mobile: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    });`
```

we add project_id and api_key in the headers of each http requests, while this works great. It also creates a problem for us

The problem is this leaves our project_id and secret_key exposed to everyone and then anyone can use these project_id and api_key, they can initialise on their applications and they can do pretty much anything that they want which we don't want

we want these secret data hidden from http requests, and I have also read everywhere hiding is not possible so is there any other way I can achieve this or alternatives.

In the very first api I have to make a request to validate these credentials if they are valid and then make subsequent requests so i have to hide from the very first api.

Proxy server is also not possible because we have to send the these from very first api

Comment: Do clients need to provide their website URL? In that case you can just connect the API key to their URL. If it doesn't match the request will fail.

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by "connect the API key to their URL"? yes I have the client's website URL, I can check at the backend that request coming from right host url?

Comment: I got it, you are saying don't send the secret data in the headers in http request, take from backend because I know the website url? this makes sense , Thank you

Comment: One question, so in initialization SDK we are taking the creds from clients, in this case that's of no use, how would we justify that?

Comment: Correct. All you need is the API key and the host URL. The rest of the info can be retrieved via the backend based on these two pieces of information